How to remove outer brackets so that they are not double-lined?
I have the following code:
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begingroup
\catcode`[=\active \catcode`]=\active
\gdef[{\llbracket} \gdef]{\rrbracket}
\def\getdelim#1#2#3#4\relax{"#4}
\global\delcode`[=\expandafter\getdelim\llbracket\relax
\global\delcode`]=\expandafter\getdelim\rrbracket\relax
\endgroup
\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{
\left\llbracket \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right\rrbracket}
\newenvironment{bbsmallmatrix}{
\left\llbracket\begin{smallmatrix}}{
\end{smallmatrix}\right\rrbracket}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\left[ \bbrack{A \\ B} \right]_{A, B=0}^{\infty}$
\end{document}

which produces

Question: How to make this matrix without the \bbrack outer brackets?

Your question isn't very clear, you are explictly adding two open and two close brackets then ask how to only have one. Surely the answer is just to add the bracket once? (changing the mathcode of [ will make your code incompatible with almost everything, are you sure you want to do that?

do not routinely add \RequirePackage{luatex85} only add it as an emergency measure to work with some package that has not yet been updated to work with luatex 0.85 (there should be no packages by now, as that is over 8 years ago)

As far as I can tell, you are asking for

with just one set of open brackets.
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
% unrelated \usepackage{tabstackengine}
% unrelated \usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
% dont load with current latex \usepackage{latexsym}
\begingroup
% don't do this \catcode`[=\active \catcode`]=\active
%dont do this \gdef[{\llbracket} \gdef]{\rrbracket}
\def\getdelim#1#2#3#4\relax{"#4}
% this delcode would not be used if you make the characters active as above \global\delcode`[=\expandafter\getdelim\llbracket\relax
% this delcode would not be used if you make the characters active as above  \global\delcode`]=\expandafter\getdelim\rrbracket\relax
\endgroup
\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{
\left\llbracket \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right\rrbracket}
\newenvironment{bbsmallmatrix}{
\left\llbracket\begin{smallmatrix}}{
\end{smallmatrix}\right\rrbracket}
% dont use in current latex \RequirePackage{luatex85}
% unrelated \usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\bbrack{A \\ B}_{A, B=0}^{\infty}$
\end{document}


I'm not sure why you add the code inside \begingroup and \endgroup which was given as an answer to Changing all "[" to \llbracket, which you don't seem to want, as you aren't issuing the final
\mathcode`\[="8000
\mathcode`\]="8000

Remove that code that's completely useless without those lines.
Secondly, you define \bbrack to already surround a matrix with “double brackets”, so you do also get another set of brackets if you add \left\llbracket and \right\rrbracket.
My suggestion is to define a new environment, rather than a command. In the code below I remove the call to tabstackengine, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts and xy because they're not needed for the example; add them to your document if you need to (but note that amssymb loads amsfonts automatically). Also latexsym is not to be loaded in a document written in the last 25 years and luatex85 is very rarely needed nowadays.
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newenvironment{bbmatrix}{%
  \left\llbracket\begin{matrix}%
}{%
  \end{matrix}\right\rrbracket
}
\newenvironment{bbsmallmatrix}{%
  \left\llbracket\begin{smallmatrix}%
}{%
  \end{smallmatrix}\right\rrbracket
}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bbmatrix} A \\ B \end{bbmatrix}_{A, B=0}^{\infty}
\]

\end{document}


A slightly more efficient definition would be
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bbmatrix}{%
  \left\llbracket\env@matrix
}{%
  \endmatrix\right\rrbracket
}
\makeatother

